# How to inject variable/unknown parameters into an intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to test a few basic functionalities of DialogFlow.

The documentation is saying that you can mark specific words as parameters. I got it. But how do i create actions with unknown paramters? Example:
"Assistant, open *appname* ."

In dialogflow, only this seems to be possible:
"Assistant, open YouTube."
I can annotate "Youtube" as a paramter (e. g. appName), but that doesn't change anything.
It only triggers the right response, if I 100% say YouTube.
How is it possible to trigger the intent, when saying "Assisstant, open Google" for example? I don't want to create a long messed-up list of Phrases or synonyms for each app in this world.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Intent (including the sample phrase and parameters) that you think should be matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way here is to make a custom entity, load it up with as many example as you can, and **check** the `allowed automated expansion` option. Also, put the variety of training phrases like `Assistant, open appname`, `Assistant, i would like to open appname.` etc.
This way Dialogflow will try to match the parameter based on your examples and the position of words.

Another way is to use `@sys.any` entity for parameter `appname`. That is wild card and would accept anything you throw at it. So it might create problem. But then again you can write logic to prevent that and handle it in beautiful manner.

My vote is to 1st option i.e. `custom entity`.

Comment: Ok, if i only had patience i would have discovered that sooner. The first option works, I had already activated automated expansion, but it took DialogFlow some time to understand the phrases.